# Access - Query not executable

Tags: sql, windows, ms-access

The error is "The query must be based on at least one table or query".

The query:

```sql
INSERT INTO Gehaltsabrechnung (IBAN, MitarbeiterID, Betrag) VALUES (
    (SELECT IBAN FROM Mitarbeiter WHERE MitarbeiterID = 2), 2,
    (SELECT SUM(Stunden_Gearbeitet * Stundenlohn) FROM 
        (mitarbeiterrollen INNER JOIN ROLLE ON mitarbeiterrollen.RolleID = rolle.RolleID) 
     WHERE MitarbeiterID = 2)
)
```

[Our "Gehaltsabrechnung" table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUKWd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `INSERT . . . SELECT`.  In MS Access, this would look like:

```
INSERT INTO Gehaltsabrechnung (IBAN, MitarbeiterID, Betrag)
    SELECT m.IBAN, m.MitarbeiterID,
           (SELECT SUM(Stunden_Gearbeitet * Stundenlohn) 
            FROM mitarbeiterrollen INNER JOIN
                 ROLLE
                 ON mitarbeiterrollen.RolleID = rolle.RolleID
            WHERE MitarbeiterID = m.MitarbeiterID
           )
    FROM Mitarbeiter as m
    WHERE m.MitarbeiterID = 2;
```

Notice that I replaced most of the `2`s with references to `m.MitarbeiterID`.  This helps ensure that typos won't affect the query.

I would also recommend using qualified column names in the subquery, but this version should work.

Comment: When I execute your code I don't get the error that it has to base on a table but I get the error that an operator is missing.

Comment: @Tobi0812 . . . An extra closing paren crept in.

Answer (score 0):

Our "MitarbeiterRollen" table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pDct.png

Our "Gehaltsabrechnung" table  https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUKWd.png

Our "Rolle" table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhmYn.png

Our "Mitarbeiter" table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yniNv.png